# How to initialise a class used to store global variable to be updated during recursive calls?

Tags: python, recursion

I am answering the following question:https://www.codewars.com/kata/5622c008f0d21eb5ca000032/train/python

Where we are given a `integer c_max`, and we are asked to return the number of `Pythagorean triples` where each of the triples are smaller than c_max, we're also asked to return the largest perimeter that can be achieved by any of these valid triples and the largest pythagorean triple that is less than c_max.

So I am using recursion to explore each pythagorean triple. I don't believe the below code matters too much with regards to my question, which is: how can we initialise the three variables in the `storage class` to 0?

My intention is to update these global variables as I run the recursion calls, and when certain conditions are met that deem a triple valid. - is this generally the right approach to recursion, when we want to store something, then return at the end of the code?

```
class storage: 
    def __init__(self,largestTriple,maxPerimeter,numberOfTriples): 
        self.largestTriple = largestTriple
        self.maxPerimeter = maxPerimeter
        self.numberOfTriples = numberOfTriples


def find_max_triple(c_max):
    # your code here
    return [{}, {}, {}]

def checkPythag(a,b,c): 
    if a **2 + b**2 == c**2: 
        if checkGCD(a,b,c): 
            self.numberOfTriples += 1
        else: 
            return
    elif a **2 + b**2 < c**2: 
        checkPythag(a,b+1,c)
        checkPythag(a+1,b,c)
    else: 
        checkPythag(a,b,c+1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your questions, but regarding the first one, just do : `class storage: def __init__(self): self.largestTriple = 0 self.maxPerimeter = 0 self.numberOfTriples = 0`.

Comment: That answers it thanks. It's because I've never seen it initialised like that before, normally it's something like self.numberOfTriples = numberOfTriples. So thanks!